# sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mariadb.mariadbconnector

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb, pyinstaller, mariadb-connect-engine

I have a simple python script packaged using pyinstaller and when I tried to run I am getting this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: 
sqlalchemy.dialects:mariadb.mariadbconnector
```

although I already have mariadbconnector installed. Can anyone please help me point to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to `pynstaller` command line additional parametrs:

```
--collect-all sqlalchemy --collect-all mariadb
```

So, for instance:

```
C:\python3.11\Scripts\pyinstaller --onefile myapp.py --collect-all sqlalchemy --collect-all mariadb
```